# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string - Chart

Tags: jquery, javascript, диаграммы

Как исправить ошибку?

> Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Код:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" id="viaduct_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="4">Количество предлагаемых обьектов</td>
        </tr <tr>
        <td>Дата</td>
        <td>1 к.кв</td>
        <td>2 к.кв</td>
        <td>3 к кв</td>
        <td>4 к. кв</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3/6/2014</td>
            <td>144</td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td>73</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4/6/2014</td>
            <td>131</td>
            <td>120</td>
            <td>69</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5/6/2014</td>
            <td>150</td>
            <td>128</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6/6/2014</td>
            <td>129</td>
            <td>136</td>
            <td>77</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawViaduct() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        /*var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Дата', '1 к.кв', '2 к.кв', '3 к.кв', '4 к.кв'],
                    ['3/6/2014',    144,    134,    73,     8],
                    ['4/6/2014',    131,    120,    69,     10],
                    ['5/6/2014',    150,    128,    65,     11],
                    ['6/6/2014',    129,    136,    77,     9]
                 ]);*/

        var json = [];
        $('#viaduct_table tr').each(function (index) {
            if (index != 0) {
                var json2 = [];
                $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                    json2.push($(this).text());
                });
                json.push(json2);
            }
        });

        console.log(json);

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([json]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('viaduct')).
        draw(data, {
            title: "",
            colors: ['#5a4671', '#8064a2', '#a693be', '#ccc1da'],
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            hAxis: {
                title: ""
            }
        });
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawViaduct);
</script>
```

Comment: Что-то писал и задумался :) В общем, дело в неявных преобразованиях, чего во что - уже мозг не варит.

Comment: да, спасибо, нужно было строку перевести в числовой) 
parseInt($(this).text())